# What is The Default Starting Column for CSS Grid Items?

Tags: css, css-grid

I have this simple `grid` `div`:

```css
#grid {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  grid-template: repeat(4, 1fr) / repeat(2, 1fr);
}

#item1 {
  background-color: lime;
}

#item2 {
  background-color: yellow;
}

#item3 {
  background-color: blue;
}

#item4 {
  background-color: red;
}

#item5 {
  background-color: aqua;
}
```

```html
<div id="grid">
  <div id="item1">1</div>
  <div id="item2">2</div>
  <div id="item3">3</div>
  <div id="item4">4</div>
  <div id="item5">5</div>
</div>
```

Why are my items skipping the first column and are placed into the second one?

Comment: check this: https://jsfiddle.net/Lrfa6qp5/ you have some strange character in your code that are considered like elements (cannot tell you why ...)

Comment: @TemaniAfif could you please tell how could you find those?

Comment: I don't know, it depends on how they get generated ... are you using a specific code editor, a framework?

Comment: @TemaniAfif this was copied from MDN, can u please tell how did you figure what they are?

Comment: ah, a common mistake ... try to avoid bulk copy/paste from websites using some special code format .. always try to get the plain code or when editing the code active the option to show hidden character so you can see them ... I inspected the element using dev tools to see them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have `" &nbsp; "` characters () before each of your inner `<div>` elements, which get interpreted as additional new lines, and interfere with your grid layout. Replacing these with regular spaces fixes the problem:

```css
#grid {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  grid-template: repeat(4, 1fr) / repeat(2, 1fr);
}

#item1 {
  background-color: lime;
}

#item2 {
  background-color: yellow;
}

#item3 {
  background-color: blue;
}

#item4 {
  background-color: red;
}

#item5 {
  background-color: aqua;
}
```

```html
<div id="grid">
  <div id="item1">1</div>
  <div id="item2">2</div>
  <div id="item3">3</div>
  <div id="item4">4</div>
  <div id="item5">5</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanx that solved it for me! Could you please tell how did you find them!